# Not getting the desired output in PreparedSql statement (JAVA)

Tags: java, sql, plsql, resultset

Im trying to pass a value to a query and save the result from the column.The value need to be passed using "single quotes"

```
Example:SELECT sales_order_id FROM mtl_sales_orders WHERE segment1 = '679223';
```

The result from that is **3321688 (NUMBER DATA TYPE)**

I did this in java:

```
String query = "SELECT sales_order_id FROM mtl_sales_orders WHERE segment1 = ?";
String segmentValue = "'"+l_order_number +"'"; 
System.out.println("segmentValue"+segmentValue); //at this point i can see the value '679223'



PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setString(1, segmentValue);`
           ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            if (rs.isBeforeFirst()) {
                System.out.println("Query executed successfully. Result:");
                while (rs.next()) {
                    long salesOrderId = rs.getLong("sales_order_id");
                    System.out.println("sales_order_id: " + salesOrderId);
                }
            } else {
               System.out.println("No rows found in the result set.");
            }
```

The problem is that no matter what the value in variable salesOrderId is always = 0 and i fall into this part "No rows found in the result set."

What i am doing wrong?

Why i am not getting

I try many MANY ways withput success

Comment: You are passing in a String bind variable value as number inside single quotes - this means it searches on segment1 by String `'679223'`. Drop the single quotes if you mean to search on string `679223`, or bind as a number 679223 if column segment1 is numeric

Comment: And drop *if (rs.isBeforeFirst())* too. It's redundant and potentially problematic

Comment: Hey @g00se i need to search using singl quotes

Comment: @DuncG hey pal, what do you mean?

Comment: @DuncG i need to search using single quotes

Comment: Well I didn't comment on that but what makes you think you do? What data type is 'segment1'? (Though you shouldn't need to quote it whatever type). The whole point of `PreparedStatement` is that it takes care of quoting

Comment: @DuncG if i search using this: SELECT sales_order_id FROM mtl_sales_orders WHERE segment1 = 679223 i got the error ORA-01722:  "invalid number" thats why i need to use this instead SELECT sales_order_id FROM mtl_sales_orders WHERE segment1 = '679223'

Comment: You're getting confused. You needed quotes there because it was a regular query on a string type

Comment: @g00se segment1 is VARCHAR2(40) data type. Im a little confused. Could you please show me some code to fix it?

Comment: You don't need code. Just follow @DuncG's instructions. When it's working follow mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a string value use a bind variable without the quotes:

```
String segmentValue = ""+l_order_number; 
stmt.setString(1, segmentValue);`
```

Comment: ohhh, yeah!! that was all.
I got cunfused but now i get it :).
Thank you!